# Communicate with an Exchange Server 2003 mailbox

Tags: exchange-server

I'm searching for some way to gain access to an Exchange Server 2003 mailbox
using XMLHttpRequest in order to render folders like Inbox, etc... on my page.

I know I have to include credentials in my url passing process, but I don't know how to
specify that. Is there a way or some example of doing so to get some XMLResponse from the server?

Answer (score 3):

This Microsoft support article [How to programmatically get the size of mailboxes in Exchange](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320071) contains code samples, and might be a place to start. Also, [How to send a simple e-mail by using XMLHTTP and WebDAV in Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314187)

This code snippet shows the basic pattern of sending a request:

```
strURL = "http://" & strExchangeServerName & "/Exchange/" & strMailboxName & "/" & 
strFolderName

Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.Open "DELETE", strURL, False, strUserName, strPassword
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Depth", "infinity,noroot"
objXMLHTTP.Send()
```